# How do I assign parsed json data to their own variable?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, variables

```
const request = require('request')
request('http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json', function(error, response, body) {
    const ids =
        Object.values(JSON.parse(body).products_and_categories).reduce((o,
            items) => o.concat(items.map(({
            id
        }) => id)), [])
    console.log(ids)
})
```

So I have parsed this json data from the url and have separated only the id's out and logged them in the terminal. I would like to assign each id to their own variable called "item1, item2, item3" and so on. I am not sure how to do this since I am a beginner and currently learning a lot as I go but any help would be great. I run my program through node coded in atom. In short it should look like "var item1 = id number" I have tried this coding to get the first id but it does not work:

```
var item1 = parse_json.products_and_categories[0].id
```

Once again any help would be great. Written simple I want each id of the json to be assigned to their own variable

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what is going on and what you are trying to do.   At the end of your question you mention you want each id to be associated to their own variable, when there are so many of them, I can't really understand why, but if that is the case, couldn't you just do `var item1 = ids[0]; var item1 = ids[1]; // and so on?`

Comment: You probably don't want to assign the results to variables.  Variables are statically defined at design-time (i.e. when you are writing the code) and you have no idea how many results you will get at runtime when the request is actually made.   You should think about assigning the results to a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item1 = ids[0];
var item2 = ids[1];
```

thats how to do it